# File Mod Date in ISO?

Tags: bash

I want to return a file modification date in a BASH script, in ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD)

What shell command will get the modification timestamp, similar to how filemtime does in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the full modification timestamp (`mtime` date *and* time) in human-readable form from `stat` using the `%y` format specifier i.e.

```
$ stat -c '%y' file
2014-08-21 12:30:03.449771375 -0400
```

I don't think `stat` itself has a format specifier for just the date portion of the `mtime`, but with GNU `date` you could re-format the epoch seconds from `stat` like

```
$ date '+%F' --date="$(stat -c '@%Y' file)"
2014-08-21
```

or simply use `cut` or `awk` to get the leading component e.g.

```
$ stat -c '%y' file | cut -d' ' -f1
2014-08-21
```